# git clean is not removing a submodule added to a branch when switching branches

Tags: git

How do I get rid of submodules when switching branches. I do not understand why git clean says it removed the submodule but does not. Is this a bug? Below are cut&paste steps to reproduce.

```
git --version
git version 1.7.8.4

git init submod
cd submod
echo "This is a submodule" > README.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
cd ..
git init prog
cd prog
echo "This is a program" > README.txt
git add .
git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b topic1
git submodule add ../submod
git commit -m "Added submodule"

git checkout master
#warning: unable to rmdir submod: Directory not empty
#Switched to branch 'master'

git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       submod/
#nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

git clean -fd
#Removing submod/

git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       submod/
#nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the output of `git clean`. I imagine it's ignoring submodules explicitly, since deleting them may delete unrecoverable information (e.g. local changes), but it shouldn't be claiming to remove it

Comment: Also seems as the checkout should remove it as well - especially since its clean with no changes

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's documented behaviour. From `man git-clean`:

> If an untracked directory is managed by a different git repository, it is not removed by default.

The `submod` directory is a different `git` repository; if you want to remove it, `Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory`.

`git clean -f -f -d submod` *does* remove `submod`. See my steps below (almost identical; different `git version` and hard-coded `submodule` path because otherwise `git` spits the dummy).

---

### Steps

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4 # Note, different git-version.
```

#### Make the two repositories

```
git init submod
cd submod
echo "This is a submodule" > README.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
cd ..
git init prog
cd prog
echo "This is a program" > README.txt
git add .
git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
```

#### Add `submod` as a `git submodule` in `topic1` branch.

```
git checkout -b topic1
git submodule add /Users/simont/sandbox/SOTESTING/Subdir-testing/submod
git commit -m "Added submodule"
```

#### Now for the interesting section.

```
$ git checkout master
warning: unable to rmdir submod: Directory not empty
Switched to branch 'master'

git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       submod/
#nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

#### Attempt to `git-clean`, then *actually* `git-clean`.

```
git clean -fd
#Removing submod/

git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       submod/
#nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ # As we can see, we haven't actually removed anything yet. 
$ ls
README.txt  submod

$ git clean -f -f -d submod
Removing submod/

$ ls
README.txt

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: I like the fact that the -ff option is mentioned in the -d section of the man page, but not in the -f section...

Comment: This is awesome! I'm using it as `git clean -ffxd` (to remove ignored files as well). At some point I may post to the mailing list about adding a submodule section (and maybe adding a hint in the error message).

Comment: This solution worked for me at first. But when switching back to the branch with the submodule, the files for it were gone. So I had to update the submodule again, and at that point I was back at the beginning with the same problem.

Comment: The solution provided is temporary as @anas said we are back to square one on checking back and restoring the repository. Anyone else found a better solution to this problem lately ?

Comment: git -f -f -d <submod> doesn't work in version 2.5.0.

Comment: Great answer but `-ffd` may be better flags than `-f -f -d` for some depending on environment... @rickfoosusa just do `git -ffd` or `git -f -f -d` without mentioning any modules... I am guessing like me you have a branch with modules not in other branches and your switching between...

Answer (score 20):

To remove the "leftover" submodules after checking out a different branch, you can run the following.
This command will recursively clean the main repository and all submodules.
**Warning: this will remove all untracked files as well.**

```
git clean -xffd && git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xffd
```

To see which files will be deleted without actually deleting yet, add the -n flag.

```
git clean -nxffd && git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -nxffd
```

Key to the command is the double-f passed to Git clean.
Without that, Git will not remove folders that are a submodule (i.e. folders containing a .git subfolder).

Comment: BE WARY, the `x` in above suggestion removes all `.gitignore` ignored files, which might not be the desired result. Other than that it seems rather effective.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, I used the accepted answer successfully (with `git clean -ffd`)... but for whatever complicated reason that wasn't quite enough in my use case.  I still had a few untracked files/directories left behind in a submodule or two (out of a fairly large collection).

I could NOT employ the shotgun `git clean -xffd` approach, as I have untracked, **ignored** files and directories which need to be left in place.

What worked for me was to:

- EXCLUDE IGNORING my problem child submodules recursively (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/3220983).
- Run `git clean -ffd` twice!!

I think these steps were needed because the `.gitignore`s in the repo / submodules must have been interfering (despite the fact I couldn't quite determine exactly why!).  The second round of the cleaning might (?) resolve the issue of having **nested** `.gitignore`s which are removed by the first clean, after still causing some undesired effect, but with those gone running the clean again finishes the job?