# Git: how to ignore new submodule of a branch after switch to another branch?

Tags: git

I'm working with three branches

```
master
develop
feature-new-theme
```

Where `feature-new-theme`is a fork of develop.

In `feature-new-theme` I've added a new git submodule, called `bootswatch`, in `protected/vendor/bootswatch` dir.

It's all ok until this day.

I do a 'freezing commit': commit all files and subdir on `feature-new-theme` with message `'freeze'`. So I've nothing untracked and nothing changed to commit.

Then I create an hotfix branch forking `master`.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b hotfix-1.35.3 master
```

**When I do a `git status` I see `protected/vendor/bootswatch` as untracked. Why ?!**

So I created a `.gitignore` file into `protected/vendor` with this content

```
bootswatch/
```

I committed `.gitignore` into `hotfix`, but still I see the untracked dir doing a `git status`.

```
git status

# On branch hotfix-1.35.5
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       protected/vendor/bootswatch/
```

**Why? How to switch from a branch with a submodule to another without it in the right git way?**

Edit to reply common questions:

- `feature-new-theme` has never been merged into `master`, because new feature will be merged only into `develop`, and only at release stage we create a `release-x.y.z` branch, do bump version, do small fixes and then merge `release-x.y.z` branch into `master` and into `develop`
- the new submodule dir is untracked both on `master` and on `hotfix` branches

Comment: Has `feature-new-theme` been merged into `master`? Is your submodule directory untracked on `master`, or only on the `hotfix` branch?

Comment: @CraigOtis: i replied to you directly editing the question, see the edit at the end. And "thanks" for trying to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it is not required by `master` and `hotfix`, you can easily delete it.

It won't affect your `feature-new-theme` branch (if you `submodule init/update` after checking out back to it), it will clean up your current repo state.

Of course, it is not "the best conceivable way", because it requires to do non-git stuff. Of course you could try with `git clean` as well.

You can find complains on this behaviour all around the internet, like [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/warning-unable-to-rmdir-my-module-Directory-not-empty-td5704705.html) or [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-clean-is-not-removing-a-submodule-added-to-a-branch-when-switching-branches-td7297679.html).

This link gives some information: [git clean is not removing a submodule added to a branch when switching branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314365/git-clean-is-not-removing-a-submodule-added-to-a-branch-when-switching-branches)

So the way with `git clean` would be:

```
git clean -f -f -d
```

Comment: this nukes the submodule repository

Comment: Yes, it nukes the submod, but the init/update brings it back from the dead.