# Git manage submodule on branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule on a development branch that isn't present on other branches. Everytime I switch branches I get a message like this:

```
warning: unable to rmdir master/images/development/fakeapi: Directory not empty
```

When I look in the directory the submodule files are still there even when I've switched to the branch with no submodule.

Is there a way to deal with this so I don't have to manually remove the submodule files after switching branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be documented in [Issues with Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules) and it involves by default some manual command.

> Switching branches with submodules in them can also be tricky.
>   If you create a new branch, add a submodule there, and then switch back to a branch without that submodule, you still have the submodule directory as an untracked directory

[Solution: `git clean -ffd <submodule>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761699/6309)

> If you do remove that directory and then switch back to the branch that has that submodule, you will need to run `submodule update --init` to repopulate it.

You have more on those operations in "[Working with Git Submodules in MantisBT](https://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:git_submodules)"

> Is there a way to deal with this so I don't have to manually remove the submodule files after switching branches?

---

> Is there a way to deal with this so I don't have to manually remove the submodule files after switching branches?

Check if `git checkout -f` can help

Comment: `git checkout -f` doesn't help. `git clean -ffd` (not submodule name) does.