# How do i add a git submodule to a specific branch of the parent repo?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

Say i have a repo that has two branches: `main` and `feature`. Now i want my `feature` branch to depend on another repo as a submodule but i want that submodule to be visible only to that `feature` branch not to the `main` branch.
I have already tried:

1. switch to `feature` branch
2. add my submodule there
3. switch back to `main` branch, but here the submodule remains visible which i don't want.

How is it possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git clean is not removing a submodule added to a branch when switching branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314365/git-clean-is-not-removing-a-submodule-added-to-a-branch-when-switching-branches)

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that people still call them "sob"-modules. Submodules are good for some very specific uses; this isn't one of them. They might still be your best bet, they just have this rough edge here.